# Copy and paste javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a spreadsheet using javascript and running it using node.js.
The aim is to have a set of methods to be able to manipulate the data.
The copy and paste functionalities are not working. those are the methods I am using:
getRaw:

```
getRaw(index) {
    if (this.cells.has(index.label)) {
      logger.log(`Getting raw value for index ${index.label}`);
      return this.cells.get(index.label);
    }
    //  if cell not found -> Default to empty string
    return '';
    // return index.label; // fake data
  }
```

set:

```
 /** Set the value at the given cell.
   *
   * @param {models.Index} index the cell to set
   * @param {String} raw the value of the cell
   */
  set(index, raw) {
    this.cells.set(index.label, raw);
    logger.log(`Setting value for index ${index.label}: ${raw}`);
    // throw Error(`set ${index.label} = ${raw}`);
  }
```

setFormat, applyFormat:

```
setFormat(index, type, spec) {
    this.formats.set(index.label, { type, spec });
    logger.log(`Setting format for index ${index.label}: ${type}`);
    // let specStr =
    //   spec && spec.resolvedOptions && JSON.stringify(spec.resolvedOptions());
    // throw Error(`setFormat ${index.label} ${type} ${specStr}`);
  }

  getFormat(index) {
    const label = index.label;
    if (this.formats.has(label)) {
      return this.formats.get(label);
    }
    // if no set -> default
    return { type: 'default', spec: null };
  }
  applyFormat(value, format) {
    switch (format.type) {
      case 'number':
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return value.toLocaleString(undefined, format.spec);
        }
        break;
      case 'datetime':
        if (value instanceof Date) {
          return value.toLocaleString(undefined, format.spec);
        }
        break;
      default:
        // for default format -> no formatting
        return value;
    }
    // if there is no match -> return without format
    return value;
  }
```

Then I am using another file to do the UI in the terminal. The important part is:

```
beginCopy() {
        this.selectingFrom = this.cursor;
        this.selectingTo = this.cursor;
        this.copiedValue = this.engine.getRaw(this.cursor);
        this.finishSelecting();
    }

    paste() {
        if (this.selectingFrom == null || this.copiedValue == null) {
            this.message = "Select a cell to paste into and copy a value first";
            return;
        }

        const copiedValue = this.copiedValue;

        // Paste the copied value into each cell within the selected range
        for (const index of this.selection.indices) {
            this.engine.set(index, copiedValue);
        }

        // Finish selecting after pasting
        this.finishSelecting();
    }
```

However, it is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: What have you done to debug your issue?